# How to use joomla language in a script?

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, javascript, multilingual

I'm developing a module, in my template (MyModule/tmpl/default.php) I'm able to bring my language string to my script by doing this :

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
Mymodule.options.mydz = {
    DefaultMessage: "<?php echo JText::_('MOD_MYMODULE_DEFAULT_MESSAGE');?>" }; 
</script>
```

I'm wondering if I could call my text with Javascript and without MooTools. I found this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Mymodule.options.mydz = {
    DefaultMessage: (Joomla.JText._('MOD_MYMODULE_DEFAULT_MESSAGE'))
};
</script>
```

But instead of showing my text the browser return "undefined"... I don't know if it still applies, but I read that's because Joomla.JText._ [is a function who needs MooTools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16726237/5842496).

Should I keep showing text via PHP or there is a better way of using multi-language?

Comment: Using PHP is the simplest way to overcome your problem. Why make things complicated? Whole Joomla is based on PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 

Why make things complicated? : Because I wish to use Ajax and give different answers without refreshing the page, my goal is to improve user experience. Otherwise my second answer is probably not a good answer, but I will go with "Curiosity" I also like to learn new stuff, learn ways of doing things and understand Joomla! programmation.

Comment: Ajax is definitely worth a shot! Even I use it in my custom PHP modules.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/4839), as of Joomla 3.3.0 core.js was rewritten in jQuery, including `Joomla.JText`. If you're using that version or later and core.js is loading on our page, then the Mootools issue shouldn't be the cause. If core.js isn't present on the page then you'll want to include it via `JHtmlBehavior::core()` and try again.

As for the question of whether to use PHP or `Joomla.JText`... I don't think that in the scope of this site (because it's a opinion question about coding styles).

Answer (score 1):

Very well, I use this structure to do the translations in my JS, come on:

1. In the view.html.php file structure put this command

   ```
   JText :: script ('fixed translation variable');
   ```
2. Now you can use it in JS referenced in view.html.php and add

   ```
   Joomla.JText ._ ('fixed translation variable')
   ```

Ready with that we have the use of translation.